# Batch script to run command multiple times changing parameter based on input

Tags: loops, variables, batch-file

I'm trying to expand on my batch script. I want to have the user be able to enter multiple numbers in the "Which session ID would you like to log off (1-300)" prompt. So that when the command runs and the user put 1 2 3 5 in the prompt, it'll loop
    `psexec\\%Machine% logoff 1` 
and repeat with 2, 3, 5. Any ideas? Does this at least make sense?

My current code is:

```
`
:LogOff
ECHO Which session ID would you like to log off (1-300)
SET ID=
set /P ID=#
psexec \\%Machine% logoff %ID%
::**********************************************
ECHO Would you like to log another ID off? (Y/N)
SET /P INPUT=
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='y' GOTO LogOff
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='' GOTO MachineMenu
GOTO MachineMenu`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of your existing `psexec` line,

```
for %%a in (%ID%) do psexec \\%Machine% logoff %%a
```

which will step through the list you input into ID. Separate the list with spaces or commas or semicolons or a mixture as you wish.

Comment: Wow. That was extremely simple. Thank you! What exactly does that statement break down to? Like, what is the %%a actually mean?

Comment: `cmd.exe` emulates the facilities avaiable for the command-line processor in MSDOS v5, with enhancements; in fact the enhancements are used more nowadays than the original and still-supported functionality. This is an example of the use of that original functionality - a simple list of elements which is contained in `id`. The *metavariable* `a` is assigned each value in the list in turn and the `do` executed for each value assigned. In the same way as `%id%` accesses the value of `id` `%%a` accesses the metavariable's value. From the prompt, `for/?|more` will provide more info.